# Is fopen() a thread safe function in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mutex

If I use fopen() call to open a same file in multi-thread, and write data to the file. Should I use a mutex to ensure the data won't be disordered?

Comment: The issue isn't with fopen(), but how you write to the file.  You need to do something (a mutex is one example) to keep the writes under control.

Comment: "Record lock" is also an option. It enables you to lock different range of the file. Different threads can write different parts of the file at the same time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If two threads both open the same file with `fopen()`, they will each have independent file streams (`FILE *`) backed by independent file descriptors referring to the same file.  You can write independently to the two file streams, but the net result on the file will depend on where the threads write and when they flush the file stream.  The results are unpredictable unless you control where each thread is writing.  The simplest thing is to make sure both threads use the same file stream, but you probably still need to coordinate between the threads.  Note that POSIX requires the C functions to give coordinated access to the file stream — see [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) which imposes the requirement that

> All functions that reference `(FILE *)` objects, except those with names ending in `_unlocked`, shall behave as if they use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` internally to obtain ownership of these (FILE *) objects.

If you open the file in append mode in both threads, then the writes would be safely at the end of the file each time, but you still have to worry about flushing the data before the buffer fills.

Incidentally, if you open the file in append mode (`O_APPEND` with `open()`, using `"a"` with `fopen()`), then all writes should be at the end of the file, and you should not get into trouble with interleaved writes — unless, perhaps, your independent threads are using file streams and writing more than a buffer-full at a time, or they are using `fflush()` after writing parts of each line of output, or they are using `write()` or one of its myriad relatives to write parts of a line each time.  There are ways to run into problems even with append mode, but you typically have to be trying to run into them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, if I access (read/write) *differen* files at the same time, should I expect any problem?

Comment: @ransh: If two file streams are opened on different files, there will be no problem.  If they're opened on the same file, there will be problems.

Answer (score 2):

`fopen()` is *reenterable*, and you can have as many descriptors pointing to the same file as you like.

What you get as a result of reading/writing from/to the file using multiple descriptors is not a thread safety question, but rather concurrent file access, which in most cases (apart from when the file is read-only) won't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a thread safe open file write you can open multiple files and it just write to the file sequentially. 
I think the below code can be still optimized with time sync and popping out unused files to maintain cache

Any suggestion is welcome

```
class OpenFile
{
    string fileName;
    static map<string, unique_ptr<mutex>> fmap;
    bool flag;
public :
    OpenFile(string file) : fileName(file) {
        try {
            if(checkFile(file))
            {
                flag = false;
                fmap.emplace(file, make_unique<mutex>());
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        catch(string str)
        {
            cout << str << endl;
        }
    }
    void writeToFile(const string& str) const
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lck(*fmap.find(fileName)->second);
            ofstream ofile(fileName, ios::app);
            ofile << "Writing to the file " << str << endl;
            ofile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            ofstream ofile(fileName, ios::app);
            ofile << "Writing to the file " << str << endl;
            ofile.close();
        }
    }
    string ReadFile() const
    {
        string line;
        if (flag)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lck(*fmap.find(fileName)->second);
            ifstream ifile(fileName, ios::in);
            getline(ifile, line);
            ifile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            ifstream ifile(fileName, ios::in);
            getline(ifile, line);
            ifile.close();
        }
        return line;
    }
    OpenFile() = delete;
    OpenFile& operator=(const OpenFile& o) = delete;
    static bool checkFile(string& fname);
};


bool OpenFile::checkFile(string& fname)
{
    if (fmap.find(fname)==fmap.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you should use `mutexes`.

I hadn't try this is `C`, but in `Java` if you open a `file` in more than one `thread`, both `threads` can write in it and `file` is really messed up.

So I think the situation in `C` will be equivalent to `Java`.

Comment: Actually I'm saying that you should try it. Run two threads and you will see how messed up the files will be.
What am I speculating ?

Comment: "So I think the situation in C will be equivalent to Java." - this can easily be written as a comment, not an answer.