# C - Two processes reading the same file

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

I have a function that reads a file and returns an integer. There are two processes that use this same function and I am getting a segmentation fault.

Read function:

```
int getNumberFromFile() {

    FILE* fp;
    char* line;

    fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    fgets (line, 10, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return atoi(line);

}
```

function Usage:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    struct process p1;
    p1.processId = getpid();

    printf("N: %d, PID: %d", getNumberFromFile(), p1.processId);
}
else if (pid > 0 ) {
    struct process p2;
    p2.processId = getpid();

    printf("N: %d, PID: %d", getNumberFromFile(), p2.processId);
}
else {
    printf("Error: Could not create process\n");
}
```

Is it not possible for two different processes to read the same file at the same time? If not how would I give one process the precedence so that other function can perform the read function afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will occur whether you have one or two processes using the function; the function is faulty.  You've not allocated any space to read the line into:

```
int getNumberFromFile()
{
    FILE* fp;
    char* line;                  // Uninitialized pointer

    fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");  // Unchecked - errors possible
    fgets(line, 10, fp);         // Unchecked - and bad news if fopen() failed
    fclose(fp);                  // Bad news if fopen() failed

    return atoi(line);
}
```

You seem to want:

```
int getNumberFromFile(const char *fileName)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    int rv = 0;
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        char line[10];
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
            rv = atoi(line);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

This doesn't use uninitialized variables or null pointers, both of which can cause crashes.

Comment: This answer by you could help to overcome OP's confusion with threading :)  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806998/is-fopen-a-thread-safe-function-in-linux

Comment: @KcDoD: There are times — lots of times — when it is easier to answer the question than to find an appropriate duplicate.  In this case, the other question/answer isn't a direct duplicate, though it does cover some points.  I need to go an fix the other answer a bit, though.

Comment: I'm not telling it's a duplicate ;) .. and yes adding more details wold be great.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue has nothing to do with threads.

```
 char* line;
 fgets (line, 10, fp);
```

You are writing to uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate some storage behind the "line" pointer.  Just change the declaration to `char line[10]`.

Ps.  There are no problems reading a file from multiple processes.