# Getting an error while executing the below program in c

Tags: c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main ()
{
    /* Create the pipe */
    pid_t pid;
    int k;
    pid = fork ();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        printf ("Fork Failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(k=0;k<60;k++)
    {
        if (pid == 0)
        {

            printf("I'm the child\n");
            printf("my pid is %d\n",getpid());
            FILE *fp,*fp1;
            int i;


            /* open the file */

            fp = fopen("File1.txt ", "r");

            fscanf(fp, "%d", &i) ;
            printf("i: %d and pid: %d",i,pid);
            fclose(fp);
            fp1= fopen("File1.txt ", "w");

            fprintf(fp, "%d", i++);

            fclose(fp1);
            sleep(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("I'm the parent\n");
            printf("my pid is %d\n",getpid());
            FILE *fp,*fp1;
            int i;
            int y;

            /* open the file */

            fp = fopen("File1.txt ", "r");

            fscanf(fp, "%d", &i) ;
            printf("i: %d and pid: %d",i,pid);
            fclose(fp);
            fp1= fopen("File1.txt ", "w");

            fprintf(fp, "%d", i++);

            fclose(fp1);
            sleep(1);
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got an error i.e segmentation fault core dumped after executing this code. I would like to know where I did wrong. My main motto is: I want to read a file that contains a number 1and print that number.
I want to write the same file and increment that number by 1.After that the child or parent goes into sleep mode and then parent or child performs the same procedure again. This process continues up to 60 times .

Comment: Do you mind formatting your code so it's readable? Indentation, and `for(x;y;z)` is horrible, instead `for (x; y; z;)` is more readable. Also, `fopen()` returns `NULL` if for example the file does not exist. You MUST check after `fopen()`.

Comment: One point, the statement `fprintf(fp, "%d", i++);` should be changed to `fprintf(fp1, "%d", i++);` ? Use a debugger to diagnose the problem in your code.

Comment: The code appears to be identical for parent and child, except for the first `printf`. So only the first `printf` needs to be in the `if / else` blocks.

Comment: You've made a race condition, among other things: both parent and child are free to read and write the file at their whim, possibly at the same time. This would probably end up printing *<initial value of i> + 60* as `i` for both parent and child in the end, if not for this: `fprintf(fp, "%d", i++);`, which actually never increments `i` in the file, since you use postfix increment. It reads the previous value of i, uses that as the value for the write and then increments.

Comment: Compile using option `-g` and then run the program using GBD (`gdb`). After the it crashed do a `bt <enter>` and find the line of code that made the program crash along with its call stack.

Comment: Related answer regarding what happens if two threads write to the same file simultaneously http://stackoverflow.com/a/16807278/646887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing to the wrong file descriptor in both parent and child.

The following line:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d", i++);
```

should be:

```
fprintf(fp1, "%d", i++);
```

Indeed you have already closed fp before.